# Storing data attributes in 'class' vs in HTML5 data-attributes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, semantics

Can anyone offer an opinion on whether it's better to use the Rails conventions provided in the `dom_class` and `dom_id` attributes for semantic helpers like `div_for` rather than HTML5 data-attributes like 'data-class' or 'data-id'?

ie:

```
<div id="post_550" class="post">
```

vs

```
<div data-class="post" data-id="550">
```

Comment: this is a really good question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one opinion...

- If you're doing css formatting, use div.class.
- But if you're doing javascript stuff, then I think the html5 attributes make sense.

That way, your presentation stuff is one place, and your data stuff another. You can always mix/match too in your selectors if needed.